# Losing data-icon when pulling html via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a php function generating grid data that looks similar to this:

```
<div id="_gridData">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a mobile-grid-header">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b mobile-grid-header date-block">Time</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c mobile-grid-header number-block">Meal Type</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a ">
                <a id="delete_id_84" class="mp-delete-link ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-role="button" href="" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" title="Delete"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b  date-block  "><a id="edit_id_84" class="mp-edit-link ui-link" data-ajax="false" href="">02:00 AM</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c  date-block ">Lunch</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

However, when I call that same function with ajax to get the same data, it looks like this:

```
<div id="_gridData">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a mobile-grid-header">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b mobile-grid-header date-block">Time</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c mobile-grid-header number-block">Meal Type</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a ">
                <a id="delete_id_84" class="mp-delete-link" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-role="button" href="">Delete</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b  date-block  "><a id="edit_id_84" class="mp-edit-link" data-ajax="false" href="">02:00 AM</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c  date-block ">Lunch</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Notice I've lost all the extra classes attached to the anchor tag.

It makes this grid:
[image]

Look like this:
[image]

So my delete data-icon is gone.

I know I call 'refresh' on objects like buttons and select menus:

```
$('#_mealTime').val('');
$('#_mealTime').selectmenu("refresh");
```

Is there a similar call I need to make on anchor tags?

Comment: In addition to your jQuery Mobile, change jQuery Desktop Version to v1.7.2 and test if needed. Actually, I see that jQuery Desktop v1.8.3 is now available too. The last few Desktop versions seems to cause issues with Mobile version lately. Please test and reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a similar call used for page refresh, it will help you in your case:

```
$('#_gridData').trigger('create');
```

Here's an working example created from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/f2BYn/. I am missing your custom css so part of your styling is missing. Still ***trigger('create');*** will style jQM elements.

Comment: In regards to proper grid syntax, are you saying each row should be wrapped within _<div class="ui-grid-x">_?

Comment: It is not a requirement, multiple rows can be used as a part of a single ui-grid-x. But from my experience, sometimes there's a problem with css styling when multiple rows are used inside of a single grid. My advice would be use a multiple rows solution, but switch to 1 grid/1 row in case of styling problems.

Comment: What specific scenario caused your problem?  The [multiple rows grid format on the jquery site](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html) does not wrap each row with a _ui-grid-x class_.  Also, I have 10 grids on my site; all pretty much the same except for the content.  They render fine on iPhone, Android (stock browser + Opera), Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: Sorry I cant remember any more. I don't use them any more. This is a grid of my choice now: http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/

Comment: Fair enough but it might be better to rephrase the verbage on the "theres an error in your grid portion".  since i am not having that issue and since that us not the documented structure, it could lead future readers down tue wrong path.

Comment: Better to remove it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS urls, when you use ajax on a different path than where the initial php script executes to render the page your path's are probably getting thrown off.  Try to use root relative paths if possible.

/images/delete_button

instead of

images/delete_button